# Does git share between OS X users, confusing SSH keys when executing commands?

Tags: git, macos

Please keep in mind of the title as the following may be confusing:

I have been using a MacBook Air for awhile. I was given a new work GitHub account, but I've been programming on the default given git (which I think XCode changed the dir of when I downloaded it. it's in /usr/bin/ now). I was planning on making a new User on my machine. I'm trying to avoid the cumbersomeness shown here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/. Switching between accounts for me is going to be confusing and I'm forgetful and lazy. So if I do add another user, will I be able to remove the need to constantly switch between GitHub accounts and instead just switch between my machine's users?

It's so that I can just do the regular old git commands without worrying about being on the wrong user. Although there are permissions set for each repository, it can still get confusing and will definitely make me antsy.

If that was confusing, please comment and let me know how I can better your understanding of my issue and proposed solution.

Comment: Git/OSX will not confuse SSH keys between two accounts. If you find a way to make it do so, you can likely claim a large cash prize from the Apple Security Bounty program.

Comment: Haha thank you! In that case, doing a `git init` then `git remote add origin gitblahblah` in one project for one user will not interfere when I switch accounts to do this `git init` then `git remote add origin gitblahblah` again for a different project, obv different dir, yes? Can you provide an explanation for how git does not confuse them?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you just log in as one account on *your* computer, that's *your* computer with one account. Meanwhile, over in GitHub, that's their (cloud-y) computer with two accounts. If you add a second account on *your* computer, and log in to that account, you can have a one-to-one mapping: one account on your computer goes to one account on GitHub. If not, you have a one-to-two mapping: one account on your computer goes to two on GitHub.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you plan to have two accounts on your computer, and switch between them. That should work fine: you'll have that one-to-one mapping. Of course, you'll have to remember to switch. At least OS X has fast user switching...

Comment: @torek right about the one-to-two mapping. That's the point of the linked article that I'm trying to stay away from. Do you happen to know why git is easily able to simply pickup on a User's current ssh-agent's key? Like how does that work? Edit: Sorry if that didn't make sense. Basing that off what I learned from that linked article.

Comment: In OS X, the act of logging in launches the ssh agent. (On Linux you generally have to do this yourself from .profile or .bashrc or whatever.) The ssh agent then keeps running as long as you're logged in. It has a socket in /tmp in a per-user-account name, with local machine user protections applied. The agent handles key forwarding based on whatever keys are loaded into the agent. Switching users in MacOS is a full switch (the other login is still *running* but not connected) so now you have a different agent, different /tmp socket, etc.

Comment: The two different accounts need different login names, different user IDs, different home directory, different dot-files, etc., for full generality—but it *may* work to use a shared home directory and a single UID because of the `/tmp` socket. If you look at your environment, you'll see an env variable, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, etc.

Comment: It's also possible to do all of this by running a second (separate) agent, which is one way someone might do this on a system without fast-user-switching. Managing ssh agents is a bit tricky, but since that's where all this is really happening, that would work.